# Having multiple servers using my discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to have different welcome channels and welcome messages for different servers, I also want these to be able to be set by command. However I have not a clue in the world how to use a database or json.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should look up how to use databases or files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start creating the custom welcome messages, create two functions like so:

```
def get_welcome_data():
    with open("welcome.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users

def open_welcome(guild):
    welcome = get_welcome_data()
    if guild.id in welcome:
        pass
    else:
        welcome[str(guild.id)] = {}

    with open('welcome.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(welcome, f, indent=4)
    return True
```

Assuming you've created a file named, 'welcome.json'. Now create a command such as

```
bot.command()
async def addwelcome(ctx, msg):
    welcome = get_welcome_data()
    guild = ctx.guild

    if ctx.guild not in welcome:
        open_welcome(guild)
        await ctx.reply("Please Rerun the Command")
    else:
        welcome[str(guild.id)][str(msg)] = 0

    with open('welcome.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(welcome, f, indent=4)
    return True
```

Now each time you want to reference their welcome message, you just need four lines of code.

```
welcome = get_welcome_data()
guild = ctx.guild
welcomeList = list(welcome[str(guild.id)].keys())
welcomeMessage = welcomeList[0]
```

And `welcomeMessage` is the message you want to display. You can use this same logic for the channels. There's a lot of youtube videos on JSON basics, I recommend watching at least one to get a grasp on how these work. Good luck on your Discord bot endeavors.